# RD gateway with Azure MFA

Tags: azure, microsoft, remote-desktop-gateway, azure-mfa

I followed this GUIDE https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-nps-extension-rdg

And the issue is all my users are able to login without getting prompted for the MFA..

this is the logs I see on the NPS server with Extension..

> NPS Extension for Azure MFA: Radius request is missing NAS Identifier
>   and Nas IpAddress attribute.Populating atleast one of these fields is
>   recommended.This is not an error.

And NPS logs on the gateway server....

> An Access-Request message was received from RADIUS client x.x.x.
>   with a Message-Authenticator attribute that is not valid.

Can you please help as what is missing here...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Apparently on the guide there are few steps missing.

Looking online I found 
Go To Azure - Enteprise Apps - Filter per Microsoft and check if the following are enabled 
Azure Multi Factor Client Auth
Azure Multi Factor Connector

Unfortunately, for me it didn't work and I have a different error

> NPS Extension for Azure MFA: Radius request is missing NAS Identifier
>   and Nas IpAddress attribute.Populating atleast one of these fields is
>   recommended.This is not an error.

Good luck